# Como passar os parâmetros de uma view para duas actions diferentes ASP NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Estou precisando passar dois parâmetros de data(ini, fim) para duas actions diferentes, uma para listar na tela, e outra para gerar um relatório.
O problema que a view criada a partir da action que lista as informações na tela(Action relatorioImpresso), não passa os parâmetros de data quando chamo a action de gerar um relatório(Action PDFPadrao).

Se alguém souber como posso resolver este problema ficarei grato.

Segue action que lista as informações na tela:

```
     public ActionResult relatorioImpresso(string ini, string fim)
    {
        var cookie = DinheiroControlado.Repositorios.RepositoriosUsuarios.VerificaSeOUsuarioEstaLogado();
        if (cookie != null)
        {

            //var teste = Request.Form["Buscar"];


            //-- Classificação, filtragem paginação 

            var hj = DateTime.Today;
            var dados = from d in db.Movimentacoes
                        where d.IDUsuario == cookie.IDUsuario
                        //orderby d.Data descending
                        select d;
            var verificaOrcamento = from d in db.Orcamentos
                                    where d.IDUsuario == cookie.IDUsuario //&& hj.Month == d.MesBase.Month && hj.Year == d.MesBase.Year
                                    select d;

            var totreceitas = from r in db.Movimentacoes
                              where r.IDUsuario == cookie.IDUsuario && r.ReceitaDespesa == "RECEITA" //&& hj.Month == r.Data.Month && hj.Year == r.Data.Year
                              select r;
            var totdespesas = from r in db.Movimentacoes
                              where r.IDUsuario == cookie.IDUsuario && r.ReceitaDespesa == "DESPESA" //&& hj.Month == r.Data.Month && hj.Year == r.Data.Year
                              select r;
            //-- Classificação, filtragem paginação

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ini) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(fim))
            {
                DateTime iniDate = Convert.ToDateTime(ini);
                DateTime fimDate = Convert.ToDateTime(fim);
                dados = dados.Where(s => s.Data >= iniDate && s.Data <= fimDate);
                verificaOrcamento = verificaOrcamento.Where(s => s.MesBase >= iniDate && s.MesBase <= fimDate);
                totreceitas = totreceitas.Where(s => s.Data >= iniDate && s.Data <= fimDate);
                totdespesas = totdespesas.Where(s => s.Data >= iniDate && s.Data <= fimDate);
            }
            else // && hj.Month == d.Data.Month && hj.Year == d.Data.Year
            {
                dados = dados.Where(s => s.Data.Month == hj.Month && s.Data.Year == hj.Year);
                verificaOrcamento = verificaOrcamento.Where(s => s.MesBase.Month == hj.Month && s.MesBase.Year == hj.Year);
                totreceitas = totreceitas.Where(s => s.Data.Month == hj.Month && s.Data.Year == hj.Year);
                totdespesas = totdespesas.Where(s => s.Data.Month == hj.Month && s.Data.Year == hj.Year);
            }



            //-- Classificação, filtragem paginação

            var totrec = totreceitas.AsQueryable().Sum(x => (decimal?)x.Valor) ?? 0;
            var totdes = totdespesas.AsQueryable().Sum(x => (decimal?)x.Valor) ?? 0;
            var orcamento = verificaOrcamento.AsQueryable().Sum(x => (decimal?)x.Valor) ?? 0;


            ViewBag.receitas = totrec;
            ViewBag.despesas = totdes;
            if (dados.Count() == 0)
            {
                ViewBag.Saldo = 0;
            }
            else
            {

                ViewBag.Saldo = totrec - totdes;
            }



            return View(dados);
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToRoute("Index", "Login");
        }
    }
```

Segue Action que gere o relatório:

```
    public ActionResult PDFPadrao(string ini, string fim)
    {
        var cookie = DinheiroControlado.Repositorios.RepositoriosUsuarios.VerificaSeOUsuarioEstaLogado();
        ViewBag.Usuario = cookie.Nome;
        if (cookie != null)
        {

            //var dataini = Request.Form.
            //var datafim = Request.Form["fim"];


            //-- Classificação, filtragem paginação 

            var hj = DateTime.Today;
            var dados = from d in db.Movimentacoes
                        where d.IDUsuario == cookie.IDUsuario
                        //orderby d.Data descending
                        select d;
            var verificaOrcamento = from d in db.Orcamentos
                                    where d.IDUsuario == cookie.IDUsuario //&& hj.Month == d.MesBase.Month && hj.Year == d.MesBase.Year
                                    select d;

            var totreceitas = from r in db.Movimentacoes
                              where r.IDUsuario == cookie.IDUsuario && r.ReceitaDespesa == "RECEITA" //&& hj.Month == r.Data.Month && hj.Year == r.Data.Year
                              select r;
            var totdespesas = from r in db.Movimentacoes
                              where r.IDUsuario == cookie.IDUsuario && r.ReceitaDespesa == "DESPESA" //&& hj.Month == r.Data.Month && hj.Year == r.Data.Year
                              select r;
            //-- Classificação, filtragem paginação

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ini) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(fim))
            {
                DateTime iniDate = Convert.ToDateTime(ini);
                DateTime fimDate = Convert.ToDateTime(fim);
                dados = dados.Where(s => s.Data >= iniDate && s.Data <= fimDate);
                verificaOrcamento = verificaOrcamento.Where(s => s.MesBase >= iniDate && s.MesBase <= fimDate);
                totreceitas = totreceitas.Where(s => s.Data >= iniDate && s.Data <= fimDate);
                totdespesas = totdespesas.Where(s => s.Data >= iniDate && s.Data <= fimDate);
            }
            else // && hj.Month == d.Data.Month && hj.Year == d.Data.Year
            {
                dados = dados.Where(s => s.Data.Month == hj.Month && s.Data.Year == hj.Year);
                verificaOrcamento = verificaOrcamento.Where(s => s.MesBase.Month == hj.Month && s.MesBase.Year == hj.Year);
                totreceitas = totreceitas.Where(s => s.Data.Month == hj.Month && s.Data.Year == hj.Year);
                totdespesas = totdespesas.Where(s => s.Data.Month == hj.Month && s.Data.Year == hj.Year);
            }



            //-- Classificação, filtragem paginação

            var totrec = totreceitas.AsQueryable().Sum(x => (decimal?)x.Valor) ?? 0;
            var totdes = totdespesas.AsQueryable().Sum(x => (decimal?)x.Valor) ?? 0;
            var orcamento = verificaOrcamento.AsQueryable().Sum(x => (decimal?)x.Valor) ?? 0;


            ViewBag.receitas = totrec;
            ViewBag.despesas = totdes;
            if (dados.Count() == 0)
            {
                ViewBag.Saldo = 0;
            }
            else
            {

                ViewBag.Saldo = totrec - totdes;
            }
            /* decimal perc2 = 0;

            if (orcamento > 0)
            {
                var perc = orcamento - totdes;
                perc = perc / orcamento;
                perc = perc * 100;
                perc2 = 100 - perc;
                ViewBag.Orcamento = perc2;
            }
            else if (orcamento == 0)
            {
                ViewBag.Orcamento = orcamento;
            }*/

            //perc2.ToString("00.00");
            /*if (orcamento == 0)
            {
                ViewBag.Orcamento = "Orçamento não cadastrado";
            }
            else if (totdes <= orcamento)
            {
                ViewBag.Orcamento = "Dentro do Orçamento:  " + perc2.ToString("00.00") + "% do Orçamento Comprometido";
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.Orcamento = "Fora do Orçamento:  " + perc2.ToString("00.00") + "% do Orçamento Comprometido";
            }
            if (dados.Count() == 0)
            {
                ViewBag.Saldo = 0;
            }
            else
            {

                ViewBag.Saldo = totrec - totdes;
            }*/

            ViewAsPdf pdf = new ViewAsPdf();
            pdf.IsGrayScale = true;
            pdf.Model = dados;
            pdf.PageMargins = new Rotativa.Options.Margins(10, 10, 10, 10);
            pdf.ViewName = "PDFPadrao";
            return pdf;
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToRoute("Index", "Login");
        }
    }
```

segue View:

```
   @model IEnumerable<DinheiroControlado.Models.Movimentacoes>

   @{
ViewBag.Title = "RelatorioImpresso";
Layout = "~/Views/Layout2.cshtml";
  }
  <section id="title" class="emerald">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <h1>Relátórios</h1>
                <p>Analise suas contas linha a linha e imprima caso necessário!</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <ul class="breadcrumb pull-right">
                    <li><a href="@Url.Action("Index","Home")">Home</a></li>
                    <li class="active">Relatórios</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<section>
     @using (Html.BeginForm())
{ 
    <section>
        <div class="container">
            <table>
                <tr>           
                    <th>
                        @Html.TextBox("ini", null, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Data Inicial", @id = "datepicker", @size = "10"})
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.TextBox("fim", null, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Data Final", @id = "datepicker2", @size = "10"})
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <input type="submit" value="Buscar" class="btn btn-primary"/>
                    </th>
                    <th>                                                       
                        <a href="@Url.Action("PDFPadrao", "Relatorio")"  target="_blank" class="btn btn-primary">Imprimir PDF</a>
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </section>
}

 </section>
 <section>
<div class="container">
    <table class= "table table-striped" >
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Data)

            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Descricao)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ReceitaDespesa)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Valor)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Categorias.Categoria)
            </th>

        </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Data)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Descricao)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ReceitaDespesa)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Valor)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Categorias.Categoria)
            </td>

        </tr>    
    }

    </table>
</div>
</section>
<section>
<div class="container">
    <table class="table">
      <tr>
            <th>
                <p>Total Despesas</p>
            </th>
            <th>
                <p><font color = "ff0000">@ViewBag.despesas.ToString("C2")    </font></p>
            </th>
            <th>
                <p>Total Receitas</p>
            </th>
            <th>
                <p><font color = "0000ff">@ViewBag.receitas.ToString("C2")</font></p>
            </th>
            <th>
                <p>Saldo Autal</p>
            </th>
            <th>
                @{
                    var i2 = ViewBag.Saldo;
                    if (i2 < 0)
                    {
                        <p><font color = "ff0000">@ViewBag.Saldo.ToString("C2")</font></p>
                    } else {
                        <p><font color = "0000ff">@ViewBag.Saldo.ToString("C2")</font></p>
                    }
                }
            </th>
      </tr>
    </table>
 </div>
 </section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não acho que você precisa de dois métodos pra gerar o relatório. Pode muito bem incluir mais um parâmetro no *Controller* pra devolver ou em tela ou em PDF:

```
public ActionResult Relatorio(string ini, string fim, string SaidaDados)
{
    /* Aqui você coloca a lógica de geração. */

    switch (SaidaDados.ToUpper()) 
    {
        case "PDF":
            ViewAsPdf pdf = new ViewAsPdf();
            pdf.IsGrayScale = true;
            pdf.Model = dados;
            pdf.PageMargins = new Rotativa.Options.Margins(10, 10, 10, 10);
            pdf.ViewName = "PDFPadrao";
            return pdf;
        default:
            return View(dados);       
    }
}
```

O `form` não precisa funcionar por `POST`. Pode funcionar por `GET`. Assim você pode usar a URL pra gerar o relatório:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Relatorio", "Movimentacoes", FormMethod.Get))
{ ... }
```

Comment: Me desculpe a ignorância, mais não entendi muito bem, tipo, você está passando ini, fim, e SaidaDados. ini e fim vem dos campos de data certo? mais o SaidaDados?

Comment: Tem várias opções. Você pode usar dois `@Html.RadioButton()`. Por exemplo: `@Html.RadioButton("SaidaDados", "Tela")` e `@Html.RadioButton("SaidaDados", "PDF")`.

Comment: Agora entendi, muito obrigado mais uma vez.